# Evenly separated DIV's technique not working

Tags: html, css

A couple of days ago, I found my self with something that I never have thought before, but went on research to solve it out.

I have a menu, and inside it, I have its items. I wanted to these items to fill the entire width of its parent; I found some solutions, including these one (which I personally think is the most simple, and don't use any hacks to do the job):

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#"><div class="menu_item">Item 1</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="menu_item">Item 2</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="menu_item">Item 3</div></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#menu {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
div.menu_item {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Where I found it, there was even an working example at JSFiddle. I created a new blank document, and tried it there, and worked.
But, unfortunately, this simply doesn't work in my already complete website. I've thought many things: my tags are inheriting properties, there may be a conflict amongst previous properties, and a lot more. I've tested them all, and still nothing. The only thing I haven't done yet is to start from scratch again (for obvious reasons).

So, my question is, do you have any idea of what could possibly be happening? Anything at all?

PS: I've tried all of this locally on my PC, but the website is already online. If you want to check it out: http://geesufmg.com (just to be clear, where I'm trying this is where the buttons "Home", "Engenharia de sistemas", "Sobre o curso", etc, are - the container is div#menu and items are div.menu_item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That still works, you just need to add it to your `a` tag's parent which is `div.container` in your actual code, not `div#menu`:

```
div.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

div.menu_item {
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**UPDATE**

On further inspection of your code the issue is you are using `.container` in more than one place (which is fine because it's a `class` but adding those properties to it is going to effect other places). You need to target `.container` under a specific identifier (in this case `#menu`):

```
#menu .container{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;    
}

#menu .container a{
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/611o6umr/)

Comment: jmore009, thank's for your answer, but I tried (treating the 'div#menu' as 'div.container' and 'div#menu a' as 'div.item') and ('div#menu a' as 'div.container' and 'div.menu_item' as 'div.menu_item'); respectively, nothing happened, and each menu item was put in a row (not inline anymore), while its link occupied the whole row.

Comment: that's it! It's always this little details we just don't see... I simply forgot that I have another DIV inside div#menu...
Thank you a lot for your help. My problem is solved.